# E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/alex-p/tesseract-ocr/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: docker, dockerfile, ubuntu-16.04, tesseract

I'm trying to install tesseract-ocr version 4.1.1 on my docker image, but I get not found version although I already installed it on my local machine. Then I tried to add it's repo so I can fix the error but I got another error `E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/alex-p/tesseract-ocr/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file`.

Here is the set of commands I use inside the Dockerfile to create the docker image to install tesseract

```
RUN file="$(apt-get update && \
            apt-get install -y apt-utils && \
            apt-get install -y curl && \
            apt-get update && \
            apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
            apt-get update && \
            add-apt-repository ppa:alex-p/tesseract-ocr -y && \  # the error here
            apt-get update && \
            apt install tesseract-ocr=4.1.1-1ppa1~xenial1 -y)" && echo $file # the version I need
```

I've done many search but I still cannot install it. How can I fix this error or I use another way of installing tesseract 4.1.1 !?

My base image is python 3.7.6

Note: I can't use the tesseract docker image to avoid any version errors with the rest of my modules